# How do I manually clear the logcat filter in Aide?

Tags: android, logcat, aide

I've noticed a common technical problem with the logcat screen in Aide. Sometimes when I use a filter for the logcat and the filter is a long filter, the 3 dots on the filter that allows me to change the filter, goes off the right side of my phone's screen and this disables me from further changing the logcat's filter unless I reinstall Aide again. Is there a file that stores the logcat's filter so that I won't have to reinstall Aide each time this happens?

```
               Thank you,
                    Michael S. Lowe
```